# How to add a list or array to a JsonObject as a body of request for volley library

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, request, android-volley

i have a body format request for Restfull api like below

```
 {
    "Messages": ["Verification"],
    "MobileNumbers": ["09100000000"],
    "LineNumber": "300000000000000",
    "SendDateTime": "",
    "CanContinueInCaseOfError": "false"
}
```

I create this format by JsonObject as code below

```
        val body : JSONObject = JSONObject()
        val messageText = "[\"Verification\"]"
        body.put("Messages",messageText )
        body.put("MobileNumbers","09120000000" )
        body.put("LineNumber","30004005430000")
        body.put("SendDateTime","")
        body.put("CanContinueInCaseOfError","false")
```

But I have a problem in creating two first parameters as list and adding them to JsonObject
Can anybody help me for creating exactly like format
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the answer of my Q
I share it for someone who has this problem
The problem solve with LinkedHashMap ... I solved this problem as below

```
        val PhoneNumber = listOf("09120000000")
        val messageText3 = listOf("Verification")

        val bodymap : LinkedHashMap<String,Any> = LinkedHashMap<String,Any>()
        bodymap.put("Messages",messageText3)
        bodymap.put("MobileNumbers",PhoneNumber)
        
        val body = JSONObject(bodymap as Map<*, *>)

        body.put("LineNumber","30000000000000")
        body.put("SendDateTime","")
        body.put("CanContinueInCaseOfError","false")
```

And the output is exactly as the format i wrote in question section